# Can a Cleric prepare spells from the Associated Domain of a Subdomain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example if I am a cleric of Shelyn and I pick Love as one of my domains can I prepare Charm Person as one of my spells?

Also if the same situation applies, can I use the granted power Charming Smile At 8th level?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. You use everything from the primary domain except what the subdomain replaces. From the section on subdomains:

> Each subdomain replaces a granted power and a number of spells in the domain’s granted spell list.

[Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains)

In this case, the Love Subdomain replaces the first level power of the Charm domain and the 2nd and 8th level domain spells. Otherwise you use the Charm domain as normal.